# Does federal tax residency affects State residency status?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, non-resident, state-income-tax

I am a resident alien for tax purposes. I have SSN.

My wife arrived in USA for the first time on 6/26/2019. She cannot have SSN. She got ITIN.

For 2019, we filed joint tax return. As required, we attached a statement with our 1040 stating that *"Consider us both as resident alien for the entire tax year 2019"*.

**QUESTION**: since we are resident alien in federal, are we full-year residents for state (Indiana) tax purposes also? I lived in Indiana for full 2019 but my wife started living in Indiana (and in US) in June 2019.